# How to run Javascript on cscript CMD

Tags: javascript

I keep getting error when running it, but when I run it in html, it work

### Error

cscript script.js

script.js(1, 1) Microsoft JScript compilation error: Syntax error

### Code

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Animated Text</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY >

<FORM NAME="f1">
<TABLE>
<TR> <TD> <INPUT NAME="ta1" TYPE="text" SIZE="20"> 
<TD> <INPUT NAME="ta2" TYPE="text" SIZE="20"> 
<TD> <INPUT NAME="ta3" TYPE="text" SIZE="20">
</TABLE></FORM>

<HR>

<FORM NAME="f2" ACTION="http://netadd.com/nam.cgi" METHOD="POST">
<CENTER>
Name <INPUT NAME="pername" TYPE="text" SIZE="20"> Name<P>
Age <INPUT NAME="perage" TYPE="text" SIZE="5"> Age<P>
Occupation <INPUT NAME="perocc" TYPE="text" SIZE="20">Occupation <P>
<INPUT TYPE="Submit" VALUE="Submit">
<INPUT TYPE="Reset" VALUE="Reset">
</CENTER>
</FORM>

<HR>
<FORM NAME="f3">
<TABLE>
<TR> <TD> <INPUT NAME="ta4" TYPE="text" SIZE="20"> 
<TD> <INPUT NAME="ta5" TYPE="text" SIZE="20"> 
<TD> <INPUT NAME="ta6" TYPE="text" SIZE="20">
</TABLE></FORM>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE= "javascript">
setTimeout("document.f1.ta1.value = 'Answer Soon'", 1000)
setTimeout("document.f1.ta1.value = ''", 1300)
setTimeout("document.f1.ta2.value = 'Answer Soon'", 1600)
setTimeout("document.f1.ta2.value = ''", 1900)
setTimeout("document.f1.ta3.value = 'Answer Soon'", 2200)
setTimeout("document.f1.ta3.value = ''", 2500)
setTimeout("document.f3.ta4.value = 'Answer Soon'", 2800)
setTimeout("document.f3.ta4.value = ''", 3100)
setTimeout("document.f3.ta5.value = 'Answer Soon'", 3400)
setTimeout("document.f3.ta5.value = ''", 3700)
setTimeout("document.f3.ta6.value = 'Answer Soon'", 4000)
setTimeout("document.f3.ta6.value = ''", 4300)
</SCRIPT> 
</HTML>
```

Comment: do you need any further help with this question?

Answer (score 2):

Windows Script Host (cscript.exe/wscript.exe) cannot run HTML files.  They can only run files that are valid JavaScript syntax.

What you have between the `<script></script>` tags, for example, is syntactically valid JavaScript, but `setTimeout` and `document` do not exist in Windows Script Host because they are DOM (browser) functions.